# How to persist data in asp repeater on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

Below is the markup page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master/MainPage.master" EnableViewState="true" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="edit.aspx.cs" Inherits="Website.View.edit" %>

...

 <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptSample">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="refLink" href='http://www.sample.com' Text='Test data' />
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkbxDelete" Text="Delete" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <SeparatorTemplate>
                <br />
            </SeparatorTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
```

Here's how I bind data on code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            rptSample.DataSource = getData();
            rptSample.DataBind();
}
```

I've also tried this one:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            rptSample.DataSource = getData();
            rptSample.DataBind();
        }
}
```

And tried to get the data on btnSave_Click function

```
protected void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  foreach(RepeaterItem item in rptSample.Items) 
  {
    CheckBox chkbx = (CheckBox) item.FindControl("chkbxDelete");
    if (chkbx.Checked) 
    {
        //Do something
    }
  }
}
```

If I didn't add the `!IsPostBack`, the `rptSample.Items` will be empty but if I remove it, the checkbox will always be false.

What's the problem??

---

Edit:
As per a user requested, here's the full page load function:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      bindData();
}

protected void bindData()
{
    List<sp_SelectAttachments_Result> attachments = DAL.SelectAttachmentsByID(Request["ID"]);
    if (attachments.Count == 0)
        divAttachments.Visible = false;
    else
    {
        divAttachments.Visible = true;
        rptAttachments.DataSource = attachments;
        rptAttachments.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Here's the markup page for divAttachments and rptAttachments

```
<div runat="server" id="divAttachments" visible="false">
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptAttachments">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField Value='<%# Eval("ID") %>' runat="server" ID="hidID" />
                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="refLink" href='<%# $"/Utils/getFile.ashx?ID={ID}" %>' Text='<%# ((sp_SelectAttachments_Result)Container.DataItem).FileName %>' />
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkbxDeleteAttachment" Text="Delete" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <SeparatorTemplate>
                <br />
            </SeparatorTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
```

Comment: please show your full page load event. are you using any other page events?

Comment: @naveen sorry for the late reply, I've uploaded my code, please have a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that there is something in your code which clears the check boxes or resets the data source of the repeater control.

I suggest creating a clean page and using the code below(which I've tested and it works).Once you have it working slowly start adding any additional logic to the page until you figure out what's causing the problem:

**Code behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        rptSample.DataSource = getData();
        rptSample.DataBind();
    }
}

private List<string> getData()
{
    return new List<string> { "1", "2", "3" };
}

protected void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptSample.Items)
    {
        CheckBox chkbx = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("chkbxDelete");
        if (chkbx.Checked)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        }
    }
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptSample">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="refLink" href='http://www.sample.com' Text='Test data' />
            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkbxDelete" Text="Delete" />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <SeparatorTemplate>
            <br />
        </SeparatorTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    <asp:Button ID="btn_save" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btn_save_Click" />
</form>
```

Comment: I found out the problem, a guy putted "Page.DataBind()" in one of the user control and causes the page to rebind data, so the values are lost..

Answer (score 1):

Use Viewstate to hold data. bind viewstate to repeater on load and also use the !IsPostBack for    rptSample.DataBind();